# Install specific ruby version into vendor/bundle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Gemfile I have specified `ruby 2.2.7` however when I do:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

I can see that ruby 2.2.0 installed:

[image]

Although, I also checked rvm which indicates ruby 2.2.7 selected:

```
rvm list                           

rvm rubies

 * ext-ruby-2.2.1 [ missing bin/ruby ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.2 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.2.7 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

And gemset:

```
rvm gemset list                    

gemsets for ruby-2.2.7 (found in /Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7)    (default)
=> myapp    global
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundler uses the value from `RbConfig::CONFIG["ruby_version"]` to build the directory for the gems (see https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/installer/standalone.rb#L38).

This `"ruby_version"` does not care for teeny_version value and only ever outputs the Major.Minor versions.
That leads to
2.2.x -> 2.2.0
2.3.x -> 2.3.0
2.4.x -> 2.4.0
and so on.

I do not now why the teeny_version does get ignored. I do know, that you could use `--with-ruby-version=2.4.1` do set the value yourself.